# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator

Tags: java, validation, maven

I wonder why my app throws this error:

> [ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator
>   [ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [ERROR]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [ERROR]
>     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) [ERROR]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) [ERROR]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) [ERROR]   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [ERROR]    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [ERROR]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [ERROR]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [ERROR]     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:215)
>   [ERROR]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.(ResourceMethod.java:162)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:280)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:129)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:111)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:88)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ModuleProcessor.processInjector(ModuleProcessor.java:66)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ModuleProcessor.process(ModuleProcessor.java:45)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:31)

When it has this dependency in place:

pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
       <classifier>sources</classifier>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: As `provided`, you're saying that the container will provide them so they aren't included in the build. Does your container provide them?

Comment: I see, I don't think that this is provided by the container... so I should just remove the scope?

Comment: If you get rid of it, the jars will be included in the (I assume that's what you have) generated WAR.

Comment: NEVER depend on a source artifact, and you also need to include an implementation of the spec in your war, not just the API - like hibernate validator

Comment: @radai: dependency on validation-api source is required for GWT. don't know if it's the case here, but never say never :)

Comment: @DenisTulskiy - a required dependency on a source artifact? what heresy is this? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scratched my head on this one, but I found a solution that worked for me.

Open up standalone.xml (assuming you are in standalone mode) from your JBOSS folder (JBOSS 7 and WildFly).  The path should be something like:

```
/{JBOSS_ROOT_FOLDER}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

In the file, look for the following XML snippet:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
...
</subsystem>
```

It'll have all sorts of XML configurations in-between.  Add the following content to it:

```
<global-modules>
    <module name="{MODULE_NAME}" slot="main"/>  <--- where {MODULE_NAME} is the name of your module
</global-modules>
```

Obviously, if you already have a **<global-modules>** section, don't add it twice, but do insert which module you want to use.  It's a quirky thing, but that got my WildFly running.

Do note that the version #2.0 in '' is specific to WildFly (JBOSS 8).  JBOSS 7 will/should have a lower version.

NOTE: you do have to keep **<provided>** in your pom.xml's entry.